# Add feature to Windows Server Configuration by AWS Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, iis, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, windows-server

My application uses the WebSocket protocol, and I want to deploy it to the AWS using AWS Elastic Beanstalk. But the pre-build Windows Server configuration not including this protocol by default.

Manually i can enable it by setting according item in the Server Manager via Add Roles and Features Wizard (Web Server (IIS) -> Web Server -> Application Development -> Web Socket Protocol).

If I want my app to work, i need connect by RDP and manually check in this option. But it is a terrible approach..

I think this task can be accomplished by deploy setting (.ebextensions)? But how can i get it?

I would be very grateful for the answer!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Add [.ebextensions](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions.html) to your EB environment and [customize your server software](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers-windows-ec2.html)

> You may want to customize and configure the software that your
>   application depends on. These files could be either dependencies
>   required by the application—for example, additional packages or
>   services that need to be run.

For your needs use `commands` option:

> Use the commands key to execute commands on the EC2 instance. The
>   commands are processed in alphabetical order by name, and they run
>   before the application and web server are set up and the application
>   version file is extracted.
>
> The specified commands run as the Administrator user.

For example this command will install WebSocket protocol feature:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebSockets
```

in .ebextensions config it may look like:

```
commands:
   01_install_websockets_feature:
     command: "%SystemRoot%\\System32\\dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:IIS-WebSockets"
     ignoreErrors: true
```

Comment: Great, thank you! This is all I wanted!
Note: this does not work for me with `%SystemRoot%` var, but works with a static path `C://windows`.

Comment: Simply beautiful ! - This solution was extremely tough to find. There is no straightforward way to enable WebSockets on AWS elastic beanstalk (asp.net core 3.1 app) - this solution worked like a charm.

Comment: I also do this one but to no avail. I'm still getting the error. How can I know that the command is executed?

Comment: I used the same approach,
`powershell.exe Install-WindowsFeature -name Web-WebSockets`
the problem is that it requires a system reboot after installation to take the configuration.
How can we do to avoid reboot?